# How to remove a single document from MongoDB using Go

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am new in golang and MongoDb.
How can I delete a single document identified by "name" from a collection in MongoDB?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you read the docs https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Remove ?

Comment: @Alex Blex thanks man..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to delete a single document with the `name` "Foo Bar" from a `people` collection in `test` database on `localhost`, it uses the **[`Remove()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Remove)** method from the API:

```
// Get session
session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("dial fail %v\n", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
defer session.Close()

// Error check on every access
session.SetSafe(&mgo.Safe{})

// Get collection
collection := session.DB("test").C("people")

// Delete record
err = collection.Remove(bson.M{"name": "Foo Bar"})
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("remove fail %v\n", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

MongoDB officially supports golang. Here is a demostration of deleting an item from MongoDB:

```
// Assuming you've setup your mongoDB client
collection := client.Database("database_name").Collection("collection_hero")

deleteResult, _ := collection.DeleteOne(context.TODO(), bson.M{"_id": 
primitive.ObjectIDFromHex("_id")})
if deleteResult.DeletedCount == 0 {
    log.Fatal("Error on deleting one Hero", err)
}
return deleteResult.DeletedCount
```

For more information visit: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-go-driver-tutorial